# This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm new to the portal and this is my first question.

The code that previously worked on the server with SQLSrv installed did not work on my new server.

It gives the following error and no matter what I tried, I was unsuccessful.

current server infrastructure

O.S.
AlmaLinux 8.9 (Midnight Oncilla)
Product

Plesk Obsidian
Version 18.0.57 Update #5, last updated on Dec 27, 2023 01:09 PM

error:
Port 1433 açık.NETSIS: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=1637121704178848

sql serverr connect eror